# Is it possible to write a python websocketapp code using the ctrader_open_api module?

Tags: python, ssl, encryption, websocket

I am trying to use the python ctrader_open_api module, *BUT* using `websocket.WebSocketApp`, not `reactor`.

First, I started with this `reactor` (with `reactor.json`):

```
{
    "ClientId": "5751_eYa1R29f9sDjWBwlCnrLN76ONFdXF7Iz6xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Secret": "Zs2hWqsV5R9cm9mdvCai6r7Xu5TaHuWCxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "HostType": "demo",
    "AccessToken": "L_c8FQqcx-lrPBJ7X6dO3iXyFxxxxxxxxxx",
    "AccountId": 25928000
}
```

With `reactor`, I was able to get some data like this:

```
credentialsFile = open("reactor.json")

global credentials
credentials = json.load(credentialsFile)

host = EndPoints.PROTOBUF_LIVE_HOST if credentials["HostType"].lower(
) == "live" else EndPoints.PROTOBUF_DEMO_HOST

global liveSubscribe
liveSubscribe = live

global client
client = Client(host, EndPoints.PROTOBUF_PORT, TcpProtocol)

# Setting optional client callbacks
client.setConnectedCallback(connected)
client.setDisconnectedCallback(disconnected)
client.setMessageReceivedCallback(onMessageReceived)

# Starting the client service
client.startService()
# Run Twisted reactor, we imported it earlier
reactor.run()
```

Then, the `connected` callback gives data from `applicationAuthResponseCallback`:

```
def connected(client: Client):  # Callback for client connection
    # import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    print("\nConnected")
    request = ProtoOAApplicationAuthReq()
    request.clientId = credentials["ClientId"]
    request.clientSecret = credentials["Secret"]
    deferred = client.send(request)
    deferred.addCallbacks(applicationAuthResponseCallback, onError)

def applicationAuthResponseCallback(result):
    print("\nApplication authenticated")
    ...
```

So good, so far. I can data from the `onMessageReceived` callback:

```
payloadType: 2101
payload: ""
clientMsgId: "140614396824240"
```

.. which is data from `PROTO_OA_APPLICATION_AUTH_RES`.

Now I try to write a `websocket.WebSocketApp` for `wss://demo.ctraderapi.com:5035`. I spent a long time trying to understand the options, particulary the `set_ciphers`:

```
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
ssl_context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2 | ssl.OP_NO_COMPRESSION | ssl.OP_CIPHER_SERVER_PREFERENCE | ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3 | ssl.OP_SINGLE_DH_USE | ssl.OP_SINGLE_ECDH_USE | ssl.OP_NO_TICKET
ssl_context.set_ciphers("TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM8:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-CCM:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM8:DHE-RSA-AES256-CCM:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM8:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-CCM:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM8:DHE-RSA-AES128-CCM:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-CCM8:AES256-CCM:AES128-CCM8:AES128-CCM:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA")

global web_socket_app
web_socket_app = websocket.WebSocketApp("wss://demo.ctraderapi.com:5035",
                                        on_message=on_message,
                                        on_error=on_error,
                                        on_close=on_close,
                                        on_open=on_open)

request = ProtoOAApplicationAuthReq()
request.clientId = credentials["ClientId"]
request.clientSecret = credentials["Secret"]
data = web_socket_app.send(message=auth_request, clientMsgId="web-socket.py")

sslopt = {"ssl_context": ssl_context}
web_socket_app.run_forever(sslopt=sslopt)
```

As far as I can see, `WebSocketApp` becomes `closed` immediately.
I'm sorry to say I don't understand SSL well.
I just need an easy SSL `WebSocketApp` that will work with `wss://demo.ctraderapi.com:5035`.

Thank you for your patience :)